# Modify batch file to open new browser windows instead of tabs

Tags: batch, browser

Here's the code to my batch file which reads a text file and opens all text in a new line in a browser in separate tabs, but I want to open each text in new browser window. Can anybody help me to modify the code?

```
@echo off

set FILE_PATH=C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\text.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%FILE_PATH%) do (
    start "" "https://www.google.com/search?q=%%A"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
@echo off

set FILE_PATH=C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\text.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%FILE_PATH%) do (
    start Chrome --new-window "https://www.google.com/search?q=%%A"
)
```